# Compatible android devices with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-touch

What android phones and tablets are compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: Or are you asking something about interoperability between an Android device and a separate PC/Mac running Ubuntu?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The link for hardware support is what I was looking for.  I just did not search thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 0):

The list of officially supported devices: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Supported_devices_and_codenames